# Cannot implicitly convert type (objeto) to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ddd

Llevo a cabo la implementación de un API con la arquitectura DDD (Domain Driven Design) pero al definir el método para deserialización de un archivo json del cual lo recibe de tipo `string`. Pero me lanza un error porque necesita una colección `IEnumerable`. Esta implementado de la siguiente manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código este

```
public class ProcesosService : IProcesosService
{
    private IRepository<Proceso> ProcesosRepository { get; set; }

    public ProcesosService(IRepository<Proceso> procesosRepository)
    {
        this.ProcesosRepository = procesosRepository;
    }


    public IEnumerable<RespuestaJson>  DeserializacionJson(string caso)
    {
        Caso deseriCaso = new Caso();
        deseriCaso = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Caso>(caso);

    }

    public IEnumerable<ProcesoListDto> ObtenerTodosLosProcesos()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


public interface IProcesosService
{
    IEnumerable<ProcesoListDto> ObtenerTodosLosProcesos();
    Caso DeserializacionJson(string v);
}
```

¿Pero no se como deserializar y tratar ese json con una lista `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Esto es raro.. por que devuelve un Ienumerable, si tu clase no implementa IEnumerable? (deberia devolver algo que fuera Enumerable, IEnumerable es la interfaz). podras mostrar la interfaz IProcesosService?

Comment: Si ya esta la imagen

Comment: El codigo en ningun caso debe ir como imagen. el codigo debe estar pegado como texto. Las imagenes son dificiles de ver a veces y no se puede copiar el codigo que tienen de ser necesario. Iproceso tampoco define la interfaz IEnumerable. Igual, para que queres descerializar en un enumerador? se descerializa directamente a una clase... hay varios errores de codigo aca.

Comment: pues el problema no sera que tu metodo DeserializacionJson no regresa ningun valor ?

Comment: Por un lado, en tu interface `DeserializacionJson` tiene definido como valor de retorno `Caso`, mientras que en la implementación el valor de retorno está definido como `IEnumerable<RespuestaJson>`. Se supone que deberían coincidir. Por otro lado, no estás devolviendo ningun valor en ese método. Por último, en cuanto al error que describes, imagino que te da al intentar devolver `deseriCaso `. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Caso>` te va a intentar devolver un objeto de tipo `Caso`. Como tu tipo de valor definido en el método es `IEnumerable`, te da el error que describes.

Comment: Exactamente el json que quieres deserializar que es una lista de casos o solo un caso?